# mouse over it, the new size of a div shifts the other div

Tags: css, hover, border

I have some div `.circle` with a 1px border, when the mouse is over one of these div the border of this div is now 2px, and when the mouse leaves it, it remains 1px.
But since the border is bigger it shifts all the divs, how can I "block" the position of the other divs?

**CSS**

```
#frame{
    width:80%;
}

.circle{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px 5px 10px 5px;
}

.circle:hover{
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="frame">
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
    <div class="circle">dflgjddsfsdf</div>
</div>
```

[Here a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/22bmJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
.circle:hover{
    border-width: 2px;
      padding:4px;
  }
```

Comment: Actually whenever I have block elements changing size on event I add extra padding or margin and then deduct the same by the extra pixel it looses on event. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
.circle{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width: 90px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Actually, I got your dimensions slightly wrong. Just adjust width and height. Box-sizing allows you to specify what your box dimensions will be absolutely, so padding and borders get added to the inside instead of the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can also emulate the border using `box-shadow` [(Modern browsers only)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

```
.circle:hover{
    box-shadow : 0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22bmJ/7/)